# Can't get the add.getSum() and etc to work from my public void writeOutput

Tags: java

I'm beginner in programming.I think the problem is in the writeOutput since when i try to add.getsum from the readInput it works. 
[image: general output]
here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
int userInput;

public void readInput(){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
Addition add = new Addition();
Subtraction sub = new Subtraction();
Multiplication prod = new Multiplication();
Division quo = new Division();

System.out.print("Pick what method you want to apply\n [1]Addition\n [2]Subtraction\n [3]Multiplication\n [4]Division\n: ");
userInput = sc.nextInt();


System.out.print("Enter number1: ");
int num1 = sc.nextInt();
add.setNumber1(num1);
sub.setNumber1(num1);
prod.setNumber1(num1);
quo.setNumber1(num1);
System.out.print("Enter number2: ");
int num2 = sc.nextInt();
add.setNumber2(num2);
sub.setNumber2(num2);   
prod.setNumber2(num2);  
quo.setNumber2(num2);


}

public void writeOutput(){
    Addition add = new Addition();
    Subtraction sub = new Subtraction();
    Multiplication prod = new Multiplication();
    Division quo = new Division();
```

I cant get to work this. It always equates to zero.

```
    if(userInput == 1){
        System.out.println("The Sum is " + add.getSum());
    }
    else if(userInput == 2){
        System.out.println("The Difference is " + sub.getDifference());
    }
    else if(userInput == 3){
        System.out.println("The Product is " + prod.getProduct());
    }
    else if(userInput == 4){
        System.out.println("The Quotient is " + quo.getQuotient());
    }
    else{
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();

    calc.readInput();
    calc.writeOutput();

}
}
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in one of the classes you didn't show us.

Comment: 'public class Addition extends Calculator{
 
 
 public int number1;
 public int number2;
 
 public void setNumber1(int newNumber1){
  this.number1 = newNumber1;
 }
 public void setNumber2(int newNumber2){
  this.number2 = newNumber2;
 }
 public int getSum(){
  return(this.number1 + this.number2);
 }
 
}' @Eran there's the code... the others have the same code except the getSum

Comment: Please edit directly into the question itself.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to experiment with **inheritance** but one thing that seriously bugs me is why **public class Addition extends Calculator** ?? So Addition **is** Calculator??

Comment: Okay. We'd need to see the definition of the classes `Addition`, `Subtraction`, `Multiplication`, `Division`.

Comment: @ShayHaned I thought extends let Calculator use what's inside the class Addition.

Comment: public class Division extends Calculator{
 
    public double number1;
    public double number2;
    
    public void setNumber1(double newNumber1){
     this.number1 = newNumber1;
    }
    public void setNumber2(double newNumber2){
     this.number2 = newNumber2;
    }
    public double getQuotient(){
     return(this.number1 / this.number2);
    }
} @progyammer

Comment: 'public class Multiplication extends Calculator{
 
    public int number1;
    public int number2;
    
    public void setNumber1(int newNumber1){
     this.number1 = newNumber1;
    }
    public void setNumber2(int newNumber2){
     this.number2 = newNumber2;
    }
    public int getProduct(){
     return(this.number1 * this.number2);
    }
}' @progyammer

Comment: 'public class Subtraction extends Calculator{
 
    public int number1;
    public int number2;
    
    public void setNumber1(int newNumber1){
     this.number1 = newNumber1;
    }
    public void setNumber2(int newNumber2){
     this.number2 = newNumber2;
    }
    public int getDifference(){
     return(this.number1 - this.number2);
    }
}' @progyammer there

Comment: **NOT HERE!!!! IN THE QUESTION!!**

Comment: Please edit your question and put the methods there! It is hard to read this in the comments.

Comment: **I thought extends let Calculator use what's inside the class Addition** , there is an idea of **containment** too , So your Calculator might **have** or **has** Addition. **has** usually points to **containment** , **is** points to **inheritance**. You should have gone for **containment** instead of **inheritance**, in my humble opinion

Answer (score 2):

You're creating new objects when you're doing the output. Either create an instance of each Addition, sub... and then use that object in the output or make it a static object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making local objects of your calculation class, make those instance variables and then use same variables in both methods, try below snippet :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {

    int userInput;
    Addition add = new Addition();
    Subtraction sub = new Subtraction();
    Multiplication prod = new Multiplication();
    Division quo = new Division();

    public void readInput(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    

    System.out.print("Pick what method you want to apply\n [1]Addition\n [2]Subtraction\n [3]Multiplication\n [4]Division\n: ");
    userInput = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter number1: ");
    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    add.setNumber1(num1);
    sub.setNumber1(num1);
    prod.setNumber1(num1);
    quo.setNumber1(num1);
    System.out.print("Enter number2: ");
    int num2 = sc.nextInt();
    add.setNumber2(num2);
    sub.setNumber2(num2);   
    prod.setNumber2(num2);  
    quo.setNumber2(num2);
}

public void writeOutput(){

    if(userInput == 1){
            System.out.println("The Sum is " + add.getSum());
        }
        else if(userInput == 2){
            System.out.println("The Difference is " + sub.getDifference());
        }
        else if(userInput == 3){
            System.out.println("The Product is " + prod.getProduct());
        }
        else if(userInput == 4){
            System.out.println("The Quotient is " + quo.getQuotient());
        }
        else{
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();

        calc.readInput();
        calc.writeOutput();

    }
}
```

Comment: [http://imgur.com/0OnLovP] I got this exception in thread error

then i tried to make the instances static and in worked .. Thnks :D

Comment: You don't need to make static instances if you are creating object of your class in main method for accessing it's methods. The image link you had provided is not showing anything.